# NSOperation performance

Tags: iphone, nsoperation

I am trying to server side connection on a background thread using NSOperation. I didn't want to subclass NSOperation ..So how can use NSOperation and how to return response from NSOperation...

Any Ideas about this?

Answer (score 2):

since NSOperation is an abstract class there is no way to use NSOperation without using a subclass of NSOperation.
If you don't want to subclass yourself you can use one of the NSOperation subclasses (ie [NSInvocationOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocationOperation), or [NSBlockOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBlockOperation)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example where to start: [Cocoa Tutorial: NSOperation and NSOperationQueue](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)